# During IISnode initialisation my Meteor application fails to connect to Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iisnode

Our deployment process follows a stop staging slot, deploy, start staging slot,  swap to production slot.

Intermittently our application fails to initialise with the below error:

We have probed into this type of issue and can point to two articles:

an iisnode github issue: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/323 that indicates to increase connection retry limits due to IIS 500.1001

a meteor issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/425 that contains a mongodb autoReconnect query string to survive transient issues with mongo db.

The problem persists... Just now 15mins after deployment the application is stable again, i guess it got a connection.

We are using 32bit node v0.10.41 with meteor 1.3.2.4 and mongodb 3.2.1 we are not using Oplog. Our mongodb is a single instance for development purposes

our url for the MongoDb connection string looks like this: mongodb://[user]:[password]@[ipaddress]:27017/app?autoReconnect=true

```
Error: failed to connect to [[ipaddress]:27017]
at Object.Future.wait (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:27)
at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:102:40)
at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.accounts-base.server_main.js (packages/accounts-base/server_main.js:9:12)
at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
- - - - -
at [object Object].<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:74)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\programs\server\npm\node_modules\meteor\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:441:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing is move to httpplatformhandler, this provided more stability.

We have also moved to meteor 1.4 this has resolved the mongo db issues as the app is now compatible with our version.